# How can I submit form and stay on the same page after require?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a code which its simplified version could look like this :

file1.php

```
$array = array();
$array = new randomObject(1);
$array = new randomObject(2);
require('file2.php');
```

file2.php

```
<form  method="post" action="?">
 <?php
        foreach ($array as $a) {                           
             <p><?php echo $a->getAValue();  
                <textarea rows="5" cols="70" name="textbox[]"> 
                </textarea>
             </p>
  <?php } ?>
        <input id="isTrue"> //true or false
        <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

The user is supposed to write answers in the textarea and click on submit then his answers are compared to the randomObject values. Then it shows if it's true or false next to each textarea

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something that the fron-tend will handle for you and an AJAX call is exactly what you need.

First of all, name your form

```
<form id="myForm"  method="post" action="?">
 <?php
        foreach ($array as $a) {                           
             <p><?php echo $a->getAValue();  
                <textarea rows="5" cols="70" name="textbox[]"> 
                </textarea>
             </p>
  <?php } ?>
        <input id="isTrue"> //true or false
        <input id="submitButton" type="submit" >
</form>
```

Now you have proper id's both on the submit button and on the form itself.

```
<script>
let submitB = document.querySelector("#submitButton");
submit.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

From now on you just have to write a proper ajax call to the url you wanted to access and you will be set to go.

If you need help with that let me know and I will throw something your way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, does the ajax part looks something like this : ` $.ajax({ url: 'file2.php', type: 'post', data: {value: value}, success: function(response){ $('#isTrue').text('the answer is true'); } ` . Sorry, I'm new I can't figure how to put code in this.

Comment: Well you either use ES or JQuery. In my example I used ES. You can redirect to any URL as long as that given URL takes care of your incoming request.

Comment: Well you either use ES or JQuery. In my example I used ES. You can redirect to any URL as long as that given URL takes care of your incoming request.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. How can I redirect to the page I'm in (is it window.location ?). Also, should I keep action="?"  ?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to retain the values entered by the user, since they go away if you submit the form. (Page reloads)
This can be done by altering the input fields. If a value was submited pass that value to each corresponding input field.

Something like that:

```php
<textarea rows="5" cols="70" name="textbox[]" <?php if(isset(value[SOMETHING])){?> value="<?php echo value[SOMETHING]; ?>" <?php } ?> >
```

This is just an example of how it would work. Make sure you adapt it to your code!

Comment: What I want to do is compare the user's answers with the values of randomObject ($a->getAValue() ) and then show a message like "your answer is true" next to the textarea.

Comment: Got it. And what seems to be the issue now? What part of it is not working?

Comment: Currently in my project I have something like <form ... action="file3.php">. So, when I click on submit, I go to file3.php where the comparison is done and the message "your answer is true" is shown.

Comment: So is everything working as it should be, or is something not working? Sorry, but I can't help you without understanding the issue.

Comment: My goal is to show a message next to the textarea right after clicking on submit, without going to another page or refreshing the page and I can't figure how to do it. Sorry if it seems unclear, maybe my english is broken. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I got it now. So you can do that with AJAX. Since you said you were new [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) is a good place to learn how it works. Another way to do it is the way I described, but it would be with a page reload.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that.